# Vuejs assign existing anonymous object to a property in the data property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i have a noob question

```
let myOptions: {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    colors: ["#800000"]
};

let vueExample = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts
    },

    data: {
        myName: 'my Test graph',

        chartOptions: myOptions,

        chartSeries: [{
            name: "Series 1",
            data: [45, 52, 38, 24, 33, 26, 21, 20, 6, 8, 15, 10]
        }]
    }
});
```

The problem is with the assignment of chartOptions

```
chartOptions: myOptions
```

the myOptions object i did create before the vue object globally, but how can i assigne the options to the data property chartOptions in the vue instance.

I think this is just a typescript(javascript) issue, but i cant seem to find the solution fast.

if i don't use the myOptions object, and i just create the object in the vue instance chartOptions: {...} this way, it all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution was very simple, i did find the culprit.

```
let myOptions = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    colors: ["#800000"]
};
```

the myOptions creation was wrong, it should use a = instead of a : to assign the anonymous object.